# TOP and DISTINCT in one Cosmos DB query

Tags: azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

First of all, I'll get filtered items below.

```
SELECT TOP 3 c.column1, c.column2 FROM c WHERE c.key = 'key' ORDER BY c.date
```

```
[
  {"column1": "a", "column2": "b"},
  {"column1": "a", "column2": "b"},
  {"column1": "a", "column2": "c"}
]
```

And then, I'd like to apply DISTINCT to items.

```
[
  {"column1": "a", "column2": "b"},
  {"column1": "a", "column2": "c"}
]
```

How can I get applied items in one query?

Comment: After retaining only distinct `(column1, column2)` values, by _which_ date value from each group are we supposed to order?

Comment: I don't need to retain order.

Comment: Please add sample data which includes the date values.  Your current question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add the `Distinct` keyword after `Select`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 c.column1, c.column2 FROM c WHERE c.key = 'key' ORDER BY c.date
```

Comment: This does not match the OP's requirements.  Not my downvote though.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can you elaborate what I am missing here? I don't get it

Comment: @MartinBrandl your answer helped me find the right syntax.

Comment: P.S. Note that DISTINCT works differently in CosmosDB than in SQL! It gives exactly what the OP asked for, DISTINCT (Top N), whereas SQL gives Top (Distinct N). Programmer beware!